# Ensuring shared pointers within vector are pushed back properly

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

I might have some aspects of this wrong, this is really the first time I have dealt much with shared pointers in particular.

I am working on traversing a tree. My tree consists of a linked list, with a vector of shared pointers representing all children for each node. To traverse, I am (to begin with) trying to do this:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void setupMesh(){
    Mesh mesh;

    shared_ptr<Mesh> shared_mesh(&mesh);
    meshes.push_back(shared_mesh);

    checkChildren(root, &temp_mesh);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void checkChildren(Node * temp_node, Mesh * temp_mesh){

    if(!temp_node->children.empty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < temp_node->children.size(); i++){
            if(i > 0){
                shared_ptr<Mesh> new_mesh(new Mesh);
                meshes.push_back(new_mesh);
            }

            temp_node = temp_node->children[0].get();
            checkChildren(temp_child, temp_mesh);
        }
    }  
}
```

My tree structure itself seems fine, but it's more an issue with how I'm traversing it, and how I'm keeping track of pointers. It is currently returning bad access errors. From what I can tell, it looks like I am inserting a pointer to a temporary object, temp_node, and temp_mesh.

To simplify the process I had in mind:

Loop through all children that belong to node[0] (root).
For each of the children, perform this same loop on them. If the child is child[0], continue adding it's coordinates to the same temp_mesh object, but if it is another child, create a new mesh to store it, and all first children of it.
Any new meshes should have a pointer pushed back into the meshes vector (vector>).

Does anyone have advice on how I could do this more efficiently, or where I'm going wrong with handling these pointers in memory.

Comment: Please [edit] this down to a [mcve] instead of (what looks like) your full code -- that is, remove unrelated code until you get the shortest readable, compileable bit of code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hopefully this suffices now!

Comment: (It's a moot point now, since someone answered, but for the sake of completeness:) Very nearly! Add an example `main` and definitions of `Node` and `Mesh` that contain _just_ enough to replicate the problem. It needs to be Complete -- that is, if I copy/paste the code you provide into my editor, it compiles, runs, and demonstrates the issue. The article I linked in my first comment gives a better description than I ever could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is currently returning bad access errors.

Then that's what you should worry about as your first priority. That's a serious bug.

> From what I can tell, it looks like I am inserting a pointer to a temporary object, temp_node, and temp_mesh.

This aren't "temporary" objects, that means something different (why do you keep using "temp" in your variable names?), but you're right about the problem:

```
shared_ptr<ofMesh> shared_mesh(&temp_mesh);
```

This creates a `shared_ptr` which *owns* the pointer `&temp_mesh` and so will delete it when there are no more `shared_ptr` objects that share ownership of that pointer.

But that pointer is the address of an automatic variable (aka stack variable) which goes out of scope at the end of the block. You don't "own" that object, the block scope of that function manages it automatically.  If you don't own it then you can't give ownership of it to the `shared_ptr`, because it's not yours to give away.

When the scope ends the automatic variable `temp_mesh` will be destroyed automatically, but there are still `shared_ptr` objects that hold that pointer, thinking they own it. When you try to access the object through those `shared_ptr` objects you access a destroyed object, after its lifetime has ended. Then when there are no more `shared_ptr` objects that own the pointer it will be deleted, but it wasn't created with `new` so that's a serious bug. (You get this right in the other function, so I'm not sure why you've done it wrong in `setupMesh`).

If you want a `shared_ptr` to own an object you need to create it with `new`, or preferably create it with `std::make_shared`: *

```
shared_ptr<ofMesh> mesh = std::make_shared<ofMesh>();
mesh0->setMode(OF_PRIMITIVE_LINE_STRIP);
mesh->setupIndicesAuto();
mesh->addVertex(root->location);
mesh->addColor(ofColor(0));

meshes.push_back(shared_mesh);

checkChildren(root, mesh.get());
```

This creates an object that is owned by a `shared_ptr` right away, so there's no problem of transferring ownership of something that can't be owned by a `shared_ptr`.

---

<sub>* Or you can use a "null deleter" but that's way too advanced for this answer, and won't make it OK to use automatic variables like this.</sub>

Comment: This is great, you've really helped me clear up some of my understanding of this. It's no longer throwing any errors. Evidently the tree I was creating was MUCH larger than I thought it was, so now I'm off to new problems. Thanks!