# Deleting a dynamically allocated object containing a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This problem is a very simple fix, but I am still lacking some understanding about the use of shared_ptr.

Here is some test code I wrote to replicate the problem I am having.

**Sample 1**

```
#include <memory>

class Test
{
  public:
    Test(int * pointer) : _pointer(pointer) {}
    ~Test() {}
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> _pointer;
};

int main()
{
  int test_int = 5;
  Test * test_object = new Test(&test_int);
  delete test_object;
  return 0;
}
```

When running this code, the Visual Studio debugger triggers a breakpoint at the end of the Test destructor.

I already know what I need to do this fix this problem. Simply make the test constructor take in a shared_ptr like so.

**Sample 2**

```
#include <memory>

class Test
{
  public:
    Test(std::shared_ptr<int> pointer) : _pointer(pointer) {}
    ~Test() {}
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> _pointer;
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> test_int = std::make_shared<int>(5);
  Test * test_object = new Test(test_int);
  delete test_object;
  return 0;
}
```

Even though I partially understand the problem and know how to fix this, I do not fully understand why the code in *Sample 1* does not work. I am really just looking for someone with more knowledge about shared_ptr to clear this up for me.

Thanks.

Comment: [I don't think I can answer this better than Jonathan Wakely did about an hour ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354917/4581301)

Comment: Yes, my answer there applies to this too, as it's the same mistake.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Good, well-worded question by the way.